# How to skip testcases in apidog? Is there any alternative of setNextRequest for apiddog like in postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I want to skip nextrequest in apidog testcases. In postman we have `postman.setNextRequest("request_name");` to skip the next request. Is there any alternative to skip the same in apiDog?

I tried `postman.setNextRequest("request_name")` the same in apidog but couldn't get.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use their “IF” feature to solve this problem. Set up a IF step, and only run some requests when the IF condition is true. You can set a condition that is definitely impossible to succeed, and thus completely skip some requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).